# image full screen with Text (_getTellText(text) Expanded flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to make the image full screen with
Text (_getTellText(text) end the screen, inside the screen.
 the buttons start and next in Other Expanded .
Can't expand the image although I've tried several methods
The image is not sized to a full screen has a space
and i dont know how put _getTellText(text) bottom .

```
    _getPage({Color bgColor, Image image, String text, int index, String hint}) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(



      color: bgColor,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 8,

            child: image,

          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: _getPageNav(),

                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this will work for you. As I didn't completely understand your question but as far as I understood, you meant, you wanted to set an Image to occupy complete screen with text on bottom, here I have used an image that was not at all portrait and have it fit the entire screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FullScreenImage('https://flutter.dev/images/flutter-logo-sharing.png','Flutter'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FullScreenImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String text;
  FullScreenImage(this.image,this.text);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child:Image.network(
            image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ), ),
          Positioned(
          bottom:0,
          child:Text(text,),),
        ],

    );
  }
}
```